# Using list comprehension to concatenate pairs of values from related dictionaries

Tags: python

My goal is to build a list that uses the key of the first dictionary(IDENTITY) with values from the second dictionary(DATA).

I am trying to concatenate the values(from DATA) by position to form a single list. The values of IDENTITY dictate which DATA values will be assigned to the key in IDENTITY.

For example, in IDENTITY the key '0001' has 'Alpha' and 'Bravo'. In DATA, 'Alpha' and 'Bravo are both assigned lists. The goal is to concatenate the two lists so that we get a single list, of the same length as the original. Hopefully the example below makes it more clear.

## IDENTITY Dictionary:

```
IDENTITY = {
            '0001': ['Alpha', 'Bravo'],              
            '0011': ['Alpha', 'Charlie'],
            '0111': ['Charlie', 'Bravo']
           }
```

## DATA Dictionary:

```
DATA = {
        'Alpha': ['A', 'B', 'X'],
        'Bravo': ['B', 'C', 'Y'],
        'Charlie': ['C', 'D', 'Z']
       }
```

## What the output will look like:

```
OUTPUT = [
          ['0001', 'AB', 'BC', 'XY'],
          ['0011', 'AC', 'BD', 'XZ'],
          ['0111', 'CB', 'DC', 'ZY']
         ]
```

#### What I know:

Lets say I have the two dictionaries below:

```
a = {'A': [1,2,3,4]}
b = {1: [5,5,5,5,5], 2: [6,6,6,6,6], 3: [7,7,7,7,7], 4:[8,8,8,8,8]}
```

I can do:

```
print b[a['A'][0]]
```

and the output is:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

I may be wrong, but I think I can incorporate that into a list comprehension that will lead to the desired output.

---

**Question**

My question is how would you do this in a list comprehension, or is it even possible with the current set-up? Should I change one of the dictionaries to a list of lists?

### EDIT

From responses so far:

Is a list comprehension the wrong way to approach this?

Comment: The output for `IDENTITY['0011']` seems like should be `['0011', 'AB', 'CD']`, **not** the `['0011', 'AC', 'BD']` shown in your question. Are you sure about that one, and if so how so?

Comment: @martineau Yes. The list should not concatenate the two items in the list, but rather the items at the same location. For example: [a, b, c] and [a, b, c] would become [aa, bb, cc], not [abc, abc]

Comment: Sorry, that made no sense to me.

Comment: @martineau Yeah, I did poor job of making that understandable. I've edited the question to make it less confusing

Comment: Your edit makes things somewhat clearer, but in all honestly, I finally figured it out without reading it. As for your add-on question about whether a list comp is the wrong approach: Depends on several factors, sometimes they become unreadable, in which case using them might not be the best idea. However that's mostly just a judgement call—there's no hard `n fast rule that can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand what you're after and how to do it with a list comprehension...just needed my afternoon siesta. `;¬)` Sorry for being so dense.

```
def makelist(identity, data):
    return [[id]+[''.join(ch) for ch in zip(*[data[label] for label in labels])]
                for id, labels in identity.items()]

IDENTITY = {
    '0001': ['Alpha', 'Bravo'],
    '0011': ['Alpha', 'Charlie'],
    '0111': ['Charlie', 'Bravo']
}

DATA = {
    'Alpha': ['A', 'B'],
    'Bravo': ['B', 'C'],
    'Charlie': ['C', 'D']
}

print(makelist(IDENTITY, DATA))
```

Output:

```
[['0001', 'AB', 'BC'], ['0011', 'AC', 'BD'], ['0111', 'CB', 'DC']]
```

**Note:** The order of the items in the returned list is unpredictable since it's determined by the effectively unordered keys of the `identity` dictionary argument.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

Whoops, I didn't realize you wanted the *transpose* of your individual letters. That becomes a little more complicated, but easily achievable with the `zip` function. Although, I would **never, ever** use a list-comprehension as unreadable as this:

```
In [18]: [[k,*(''.join(x) for x in zip(*(DATA[l] for l in v)))] for k,v in IDENTITY.items()]
Out[18]: [['0001', 'AB', 'BC'], ['0011', 'AC', 'BD'], ['0111', 'CB', 'DC']]
```

#### original answer

Yes, this is possible, iterate over the `.items` in `IDENTITY` and join the result of the mapping from `DATA`:

```
In [4]: OUTPUT = [[k,*(''.join(DATA[l]) for l in v)] for k,v in IDENTITY.items()]

In [5]: OUTPUT
Out[5]: [['0001', 'AB', 'BC'], ['0011', 'AB', 'CD'], ['0111', 'CD', 'BC']]
```

Note, I used the nifty `*` unpacking, but you could do the following as well:

```
In [6]: OUTPUT = [[k]+[''.join(DATA[l]) for l in v] for k,v in IDENTITY.items()]

In [7]: OUTPUT
Out[7]: [['0001', 'AB', 'BC'], ['0011', 'AB', 'CD'], ['0111', 'CD', 'BC']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in one line as you want :

```
from collections import defaultdict


IDENTITY = {
            '0001': ['Alpha', 'Bravo'],
            '0011': ['Alpha', 'Charlie'],
            '0111': ['Charlie', 'Bravo']
           }

DATA = {
        'Alpha': ['A', 'B'],
        'Bravo': ['B', 'C'],
        'Charlie': ['C', 'D']
       }

final_dict={}

one_line=[final_dict.setdefault(item, []).append("".join(item_2)) for item,value in IDENTITY.items() for item_3 in value for item_1, item_2 in DATA.items() if item_3 == item_1]

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'0111': ['CD', 'BC'], '0011': ['AB', 'CD'], '0001': ['AB', 'BC']}
```

> Additional information :

Detailed solution :

```
final_dict={}
for item,value in IDENTITY.items():
    for item_3 in value:
        for item_1, item_2 in DATA.items():
            if item_3 == item_1:

                final_dict.setdefault(item, []).append("".join(item_2))


print(final_dict)
```